# React Native file handling - delete image

Tags: react-native, delete-file

I am using [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) for clicking pictures. I get a file path like : "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20161228_021132.jpg" in the data from the Camera which I am storing in the state. I am able to use this as the source for displaying the Image using the Image component "Image source={{uri: this.props.note.imagePath.path}}" and it is displaying properly.

Now I want to add delete image functionality. Can someone suggest on how to access this image in the phone using the path mentioned above and delete it from the phone.

I checked the [react-native-filesystem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-filesystem) but when I used the checkIfFileExists function passing in this path I got that the file doesn't exist. Not sure what is going wrong.

```
async checkIfFileExists(path) {

const fileExists = await FileSystem.fileExists(path);
//const directoryExists = await FileSystem.directoryExists('my-directory/my-file.txt');
console.log(`file exists: ${fileExists}`);
//console.log(`directory exists: ${directoryExists}`);
}


deleteNoteImage (note) {

console.log(note.imagePath.path);

//check if file exists
this.checkIfFileExists(note.imagePath.path);
//console.log();

note.imagePath = null;
this.updateNote(note);
}
```

[image: remote debugging snapshot]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I was able to do it using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs)

The path needs to be declared as follows:

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

const dirPicutures = `${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/Pictures`;
```

Then this function deletes the image given the image name.

```
  deleteImageFile(filename) {

    const filepath = `${dirPicuturesTest}/${filename}`;

    RNFS.exists(filepath)
    .then( (result) => {
        console.log("file exists: ", result);

        if(result){
          return RNFS.unlink(filepath)
            .then(() => {
              console.log('FILE DELETED');
            })
            // `unlink` will throw an error, if the item to unlink does not exist
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err.message);
            });
        }

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }
```

Comment: UIImage still shows a placeholder instead of deleted image, after system reboot placeholder goes away. Have you find any solution for the same?

Comment: I am using `react-native-image-crop-picker` which it makes random name for images inside `Pictures`. So I dont know the image name, so how Can I remove all contents within this folder

Answer (score 5):

Though it is already answered, for anyone tumbling upon the issue, you can also use [react-native fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#unlinkpathstringpromise)

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.unlink(path)
 .then(() => { ... })
 .catch((err) => { ... })
```

Comment: Was a pain to configure this seemingly loosely-maintained library but still didn't solve the issue for me. I think I'll need to try the other suggestions (`file.split('///').pop()`)

Answer (score 2):

I also used `react-native-fs`. But instead of recreating the file path I just used the file already given to me in my case by `react-native-camera`

```
const file = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20161228_021132.jpg'
const filePath = file.split('///').pop()  // removes leading file:///

RNFS.exists(filePath)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res) {
      RNFS.unlink(filePath)
        .then(() => console.log('FILE DELETED'))
    }
  })
```

Comment: There is a bracket missing after the console of 'FILE DELETED'.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @Murtuza

Comment: I'm receiving FILE DELETED, but file still remains in Gallery without image contest

Comment: I am also facing the same message "File deteled", but it is still there in gallery.

Comment: I have the same problem, tried RNFS.scanFile(path) after deleting but black image persists in the image gallery.

`RNFS.unlink(path)
.then((success) => {
console.log('FILE DELETED', success);
RNFS.scanFile(path)
.then(() => console.log('path scanned'))
.catch(() => console.log('error scanning path'));
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log(err.message);
});`